# Determine $R(T)$ and $N(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

Can someone help me solve the following please? Thanks!

Let $T: P_1(\mathbb{R}) \to P_1(\mathbb{R})$ be defined as $T(f)(x) = f'(x)+f(x).$ Determine $R(T)$ and $N(T)$. Consider $P_1(\mathbb{R})$ as an inner product space with inner product $$\langle f, g \rangle = \int_{-1}^{1} f(x)g(x)dx.$$ Evaluate $T^*$ at the vector $h(x) = 1+x$.

Comment: Could you please show what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have no clue how to do it, my solution was deemed completely wrong by someone else. I posted this problem like two days ago @user1337

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f\in P_{1}(\textbf{R})$, then $f(x) = ax + b$. Thus $T(f)(x) = a + b + ax$.

We may now determine the kernel and image of $T$. Let's start with the kernel. One has
\begin{align*}
T(f)(x) = a + b + ax = 0 \Longrightarrow a = b = 0 \Longrightarrow \ker(T) = \{0\}
\end{align*}

Based on the rank-nullity theorem, we conclude that $\text{Im}(T) = P_{1}(\textbf{R})$.

We may now approach the second part.

Firstly, let us reinforce that the adjoint operator satisfies $\langle T(f)(x), h(x)\rangle = \langle f(x), T^{*}(h)(x)\rangle$, which is unique for each $h(x)$.

Then we need to determine the next integral
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{1}(ax + a + b)(x+1)\mathrm{d}x = \int_{-1}^{1}(ax^{2} + (2a+b)x + a + b)\mathrm{d}x = \frac{8a}{3} + 2b
\end{align*}

In order to find $T^{*}(h)(x)$, let us assume it equals $cx  + d$. Consequently,
\begin{align*}
\int_{-1}^{1}(ax+b)(cx + d)\mathrm{d}x = \int_{-1}^{1}(acx^{2} + (ad+bc)x + bd)\mathrm{d}x  = \frac{2ac}{3} + 2bd
\end{align*}
Comparing both expressions, we conclude that $c = 4$ and $d = 1$.

Finally, we obtain that $T^{*}(h)(x) = 4x + 1$, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for solving it, I figured out my error. It was basic integration